# How can Mortarboard et. al. be earned on child metas?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, daily-reputation-badges, meta-reputation

I recently earned the [Mortarboard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard?userid=3187556) badge on MSO. The tag description is:

> Earned at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day.

If metas don't have reputation, how do these badges work?

Comment: Probably would have caught that myself if the iPad app suggested duplicates... Time for a feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because if meta had rep, you **would** have earned 200 repz this day if per-site meta had rep (so even if there is no rep on per-site meta, it is counted anyway)